error[E0583]: file not found for module `sys`
Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
solana-sdk = "1.17.17"
solana-client = "1.17.17"
solana-program = "1.17.17"
borsh = "1.5.1"
getrandom = { version = "0.1.14", features = ["dummy"] }

...
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
$ rustup --version
rustup 1.27.1 (54dd3d00f 2024-04-24)
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.73.0 (9c4383fb5 2023-08-26)
$ cargo-build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.17.17
platform-tools v1.37
rustc 1.68.0

I'm trying to run cargo build-sbf. I tried to run with the tools-version flag as well. I'm installing this in Mac OS Monterey btw.

This question is similar to: Depencencies in Cargo.toml file Solana-SDK and Solana-Client doesn't work. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
